# Is it possible to apply imported xslt to part of xml?

Tags: xml, xslt

Is it possible to apply imported xslt to part of xml?

For example I have the follofing file

```
<full>
  <parts>
    <part>{more elements here}<part>
    <part>{more elements here}<part>
    <part>{more elements here}<part>
  </parts>
</full>
```

And I have xslt which is used to extract information from  structure. So when it applies to whole xml it extracts all  values. So is it possible to apply it on each part separately?
I've tried to use  but haven't succeed

Upd:
I will try to clarify my question
Commonly I have to process xml as `<part>{more elements here}<part>` and I have infrastructure for such xml. I have variables.xslt to extract common fields which is imported in other more specific transformations. But now I need to process composite xml and as long as variables.xslt contains relative xpaths my approach not works for composite xml. So I'm trying to find a way how can I apply my variables.xslt to part of composite.xml

Answer (score 0):

The importing stylesheet can do e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="(full/parts/part)[1]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

to for instance apply templates only to the first `part` grand child of the `full` element. You will need to show us more details if you need more concrete help.

Comment: I've tried to clarify my questions. Please tell if it not clear yet

Comment: No, I would really like to see samples of the XSLT you have, both the imported module and the importing module, as well as of the input XML, to be able to tell where the problem is.